# Segmentation fault when calling vkCreateGraphicsPipelines

Tags: c++, graphics, segmentation-fault, gpu, vulkan

I was following the [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Conclusion) when I ran into a problem.

I pretty much copy pasted the entire `CreateGraphicsPipeline()` function out of the tutorial code. However I am getting a segmentation fault when calling: `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines()`

So far it seems this error tends to happen when the declared memory size of the shaders isn't correct but I have tested it multiple times and it seems fine to me.

From what I have been able to research the problem is likely to be inside the shader module creation, as an invalid shader won't cause any errors or debug messages until the creation of the pipeline. Someone suggested to me the error could be in the line:

`createInfo.codeSize = code.size();`

And suggested:

`createInfo.codeSize = code.size() * sizeof(uint32_t);`

However that seems to create an infinite loop inside of `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`

My shaders are identical to his: [vertex](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/09_shader_base.vert), [fragment](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/09_shader_base.frag)

And my functions are (sorry about the length, this is vulkan and it's hard to make things smaller):

```
static std::vector<char> ReadFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "failed to open file: " << filename << endl;
    }

    size_t fileSize = (size_t) file.tellg();
    std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);

    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);

    file.close();

    return buffer;
}

VkShaderModule CreateShaderModule(const std::vector<char>& code) {
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo createInfo = {};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.codeSize = code.size();
    createInfo.pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(code.data());

    VkShaderModule shaderModule;
    if (vkCreateShaderModule(device, &createInfo, nullptr, &shaderModule) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "failed to create shader module!" << endl;
    }

    return shaderModule;
}

void CreateGraphicsPipeline() {
    vector<char> vertShaderCode = ReadFile("build/shaders/shader_base.vert.spv");
    vector<char> fragShaderCode = ReadFile("build/shaders/shader_base.frag.spv");

    VkShaderModule vertShaderModule = CreateShaderModule(vertShaderCode);
    VkShaderModule fragShaderModule = CreateShaderModule(fragShaderCode);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertShaderStageInfo = {};
    vertShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    vertShaderStageInfo.module = vertShaderModule;
    vertShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragShaderStageInfo = {};
    fragShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    fragShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    fragShaderStageInfo.module = fragShaderModule;
    fragShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = {vertShaderStageInfo, fragShaderStageInfo};

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {};
    vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 0;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = nullptr; // Optional
    vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = nullptr; // Optional

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
    inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.x = 0.0f;
    viewport.y = 0.0f;
    viewport.width = (float) swapChainExtent.width;
    viewport.height = (float) swapChainExtent.height;
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

    VkRect2D scissor = {};
    scissor.offset = {0, 0};
    scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
    viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
    viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasConstantFactor = 0.0f; // Optional
    rasterizer.depthBiasClamp = 0.0f; // Optional
    rasterizer.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0.0f; // Optional

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
    multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    multisampling.minSampleShading = 1.0f; // Optional
    multisampling.pSampleMask = nullptr; // Optional
    multisampling.alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE; // Optional
    multisampling.alphaToOneEnable = VK_FALSE; // Optional

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
    colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE; // Optional
    colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO; // Optional
    colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD; // Optional
    colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE; // Optional
    colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO; // Optional
    colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD; // Optional

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
    colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY; // Optional
    colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
    colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f; // Optional
    colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f; // Optional
    colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f; // Optional
    colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f; // Optional

    VkDynamicState dynamicStates[] = {
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH
    };

    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState = {};
    dynamicState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = 2;
    dynamicState.pDynamicStates = dynamicStates;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo = {};
    pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 0; // Optional
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pSetLayouts = nullptr; // Optional
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0; // Optional
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pPushConstantRanges = nullptr; // Optional

    if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "failed to create pipeline layout!" << endl;
    }

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;

    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pDepthStencilState = nullptr; // Optional
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = nullptr; // Optional
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;

    pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;

    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE; // Optional
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1; // Optional

    if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &graphicsPipeline) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "failed to create graphics pipeline!" << endl;
    }

    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, fragShaderModule, nullptr);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertShaderModule, nullptr);
}
```

EDIT: used wrong function name

Comment: Your `createInfo.codeSize` is correct, it's supposed to be size in bytes, and that's what you're setting it to.

Comment: The question and some of the things you say (e.g. "the problem is likely to be inside the shader module creation") suggest the problem is in `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`, but you also say "However I am getting a segmentation fault when calling: `vkCreatePipelineLayout()`". Which is it? If you're crashing in `vkCreatePipelineLayout`, then the problem isn't with the shader modules or other inputs to `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`. Do you have the call stack from the segmentation fault?

Comment: My bad I used the wrong function. I used gdb to get the stack trace of the segmentation fault. It ultimately happens in the nvidia driver, so i have no knowledge of what exactly is crashing, but the last function I call prior to passing responsibility to the driver is:

`CreateGraphicsPipeline()`

Comment: @Makogan: What does "*the memory alignment of the shaders isn't correct*" mean? How do shaders have alignment?

Comment: @NicolBolas edited for clarity, hopefully it is better now

Comment: Do you have the validation layers enabled and the debug callback hooked up?

Comment: @Makogan: "*the declared memory size of the shaders isn't correct*" How do you know when it is and is not correct?

Comment: @Jesse Hall, yes I enabled validation layers and the debug callback. It has helped me trace some other bugs, but it is not getting called here

Comment: Please add all relevant code parts. Pipeline creation might also crash if your renderpass setup doesn't fit, e.g. if you're using depth/stencil but did not provide pDethStencilState.